# How to deploy NodeJS Rest API in Ubuntu LTS 18 in apache2

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, apache2, pm2, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to NodeJS and I have a simple website that sends the contact-us information from ReactJS to NodeJS via Axios.

It is working on my local machine and I am trying to deploy it in my AWS EC2 Ubuntu LTS 18.

I have installed the PM2 already and I am stuck on what should I do next, how can I deploy my NodeJS in Ubuntu with Apache2 installed and make it run on my server even if I close my terminal. Also, what would be the API URL endpoint?

I hope someone could help me with this basic nodejs deployment in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:

1. to move the code to the server - you can use shipit.js (https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit) in order to do this. Take a look at this screencast about shipit.js and forever https://youtu.be/8PpBySjkWEM, forever is something like pm2.
2. to redirect traffic from Apache to your app. It is called `reverse proxy`. Conf file for that would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot **where-your-app-public-files-are**
   ServerName **domain_name**
   ProxyRequests off
   ProxyPreserveHost on
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:**your-node-port**/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:**your-node-port**/
</VirtualHost>
```

Change `**variables**` to your data.

So it could be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/your-app
   ServerName your-domain-name.com
   ProxyRequests off
   ProxyPreserveHost on
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4040/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4040/
</VirtualHost>
```